# Changing item of List<Texture> creates a new item

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of items of type Texture (custom class with only some properties). I am able to change the data of one of the items in that list but when I save them, and there are more items in the list than one, it seems to make a NEW copy in that list.

First of all this is the declaration of the Texture list, which is located in a static class (MainData):

```
public static List<Texture> Textures = new List<Texture>();
```

And here's the code that changes the data according to the, possibly, data that has been filled in by the user:

```
for (int t = 0; t < MainData.Textures.Count; ++t)
{
      if (MainData.Textures[t].Path == texture.Path)
          MainData.Textures[t] = texture;
      else
          MainData.Textures.Add(texture);
}
```

I have no idea why he does that. And this only happens when there are more than one item in the list. Is there something obvious wrong? Am I taking a wrong approach to this?

So, I simply want to be able to change the data in the list per selected item. (I check the list for the path of the Texture to know which one has been changed because that's a static value that won't be changed throughout the program).

Comment: Your last line adds a new item to the list

Comment: You are adding the new texture for *each* element in the existing list that doesn't have a matching `Path`. I would think that the logic you need is: if *any* element in the list has a matching `Path`,  replace that one. If you reach the end of the for loop without having done this, _then_ add the new item (once).

Comment: `Main.Textures.Add` will add a new item to the list. Put a breakpoint on the `if` condition and check the data you're working on. Something is causing you to fall into the `else` condition.

Comment: Oh yeah, right, dammit. How did I not see that! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine your `Textures` collection has two `Texture` objects in it already:

```
TextureA, Path = A
TextureB, Path = B
```

Now, let's say you try to add a new texture, TextureC with Path = B.  Let's step through your loop and see what happens:

First iteration:
`Textures[0].Path == texture.Path` is false (because A != B), so we execute the else statement and add TextureC to the collection.

So now the collection looks like:

```
TextureA, Path = A
TextureB, Path = B
TextureC, Path = B
```

Second iteration:
The if statement is true (`TextureB.Path == TextureC.Path`) so you replace that item, now the list looks like:

```
TextureA, Path = A;
TextureC, Path = B;
TextureC, Path = B
```

Then there's a third iteration, but I think from these two it should be clear where your mistake is.  What you need to do is separate searching the list for an existing item from adding items (since each time you try to replace, your loop is going to add one copy of the texture you're adding for each element in the list that doesn't match it).

Answer (score 4):

Simply do

```
var tex = Textures.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Path == texture.Path);
if (tex != null)
    tex = texture;
else
    Textures.Add(texture);
```

It's more expressive, in my opinion, and behaves like you want. Note, that this only changes the first one it founds, if any.

Answer (score 0):

The `Count` property  is not fix in a `for`-loop if you add items there., it will increase. So every time you add an item you get one iteration more which ysou will check later. It's even possible to get an `OutOfMemoryException` since you're addding textures endlessly.

You could  go backwards:

```
for (int t =  MainData.Textures.Count - 1; t >= 0; t--)
{
      if (MainData.Textures[t].Path == texture.Path)
          MainData.Textures[t] = texture;
      else
          MainData.Textures.Add(texture);
}
```